# Where clause with a decimal

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out why my query will not update my database. This is what I have for PHP coding:

```
if($sevenhalf)  {
    $update_sevenhalf = "UPDATE xcart_class_options SET orderby='$sevenhalf' WHERE option_name='7.5'";
    mysql_query($update_sevenhalf) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $sevenhalf.'<br>';
}
```

but when I execute it, it keeps trying to update the wrong fields:

```
array(63) { ["7_5"]=> string(3) "107"
```

You can see the problem. It should be trying to update every instance of option_name with the value 7.5 but the array is showing it is trying to place it in 7_5. I can't figure out why it is doing this exactly. I think the period is escaping part of the line. I don't get any errors, just that the array is going to the wrong place. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you getting `$sevenhalf` from?

Comment: Basically I have a form that is generating a field for each option_name and I need to order them a certain way for my project. The option_name is the name of each input as well so I can change every instance of that option name in the database.

Comment: why would someone give me a negative rating on this? It was a solid question and actually I needed the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting `$sevenhalf` in something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="7.5" />
```

Then you should know that PHP converts `.` to `_` when populating the GPC variables (`$_POST['7_5']`)... I honestly have no idea why, but that's just what it does. You can always use `str_replace("_",".",$sevenhalf)` to get it back.

Comment: would I place that before or after the form is passed to my update script?

Comment: nevermind....I got it! THX! Really helped a lot. I have been racking my head on this for about 2 hours.